# Is that possible to connect laptop to raspberry pi 3 through micro usb power port?

Tags: wifi, usb-power

Hello recently I bought raspberry pi 3 kit, and I hope to make a smart mirror.

Imagine If I make smart mirror successfully, and want to give to my girl friend.

The raspberry pi are assembled, behind the mirror, you can see only usb power port unless you disassemble it.

At this point, How can she set WiFi configuration?

Is it possible to connect the laptop to smart mirror **through usb power port**, and access to raspberry pi's sd card, and save some configuration?

Of course, I should done raspberry pi use that config file before finish it.

Is it possible? or better idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're out of luck on this one. For next time round, a common approach to this problem is to set the Pi up so that it can be [switched between network client and access point modes](http://lcdev.dk/2012/11/18/raspberry-pi-tutorial-connect-to-wifi-or-create-an-encrypted-dhcp-enabled-ad-hoc-network-as-fallback/). That should let you access the Pi's configuration files to update them for a new network.

Comment: @goobering I don't start make mirror. haha, just think about wifi problem before into it. I searched several docs about that and I think your comment is one of proper way.

Comment: @goobering Is that possible to when I manufactured mirror the wifi will be access point mode, and end user connect the mirror through certain device and save configuration file, and switch to network client mode?

Comment: @goobering even I use RPi3 as an AP, I should have to connect ethernet cable to router,, right?

Comment: If you've set the Pi up so that it can act as an access point, and the Pi has a WiFi adapter, you shouldn't need to connect a cable. When it's acting as an AP the Pi will appear to other devices as a new WiFi network. You connect to that, edit the configuration files with the credentials of the WiFi network you want to connect to, then disconnect from the Pi's AP and restart networking with the Pi in client mode, which should connect to the local router and allow internet access. No ethernet cables required.

Comment: @goobering It sounds interesting. so when AP mode, my mobile phone will recognize Pi, and connect to it, It is not actual internet. right? is just a local network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot connect to the Pi 3 using the mirco-USB power port. The data lines of that connector are not attached to the Pi - it is just used to provide power. See the [official schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings) of the [Pi3 (pdf)](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpi3/raspberry-pi-3-b-reduced-schematics.pdf), top left.

An alternative would be to used the wired ethernet to connect to the Pi and set the WiFi configuration, depends on how tech-savvy the end user will be. Ultimately it might just boil down to you setting it up to a working condition on-site and/or to provide support after that.

Comment: You could add a camera behind the smart mirror with motion software to create a user interface allowing the wifi ESSID and password to be entered via [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore).  This might be considered a bit creepy though.  Somewhat easier would something that used `udev` to respond to a keyboard being plugged in.