# Connect a Bluetooth Device as a COM Port

Tags: bluetooth

I've got a Bluetooth device which works by being connected as a serial port (RFCOMM) and then data can be sent via a Java application.

Within this Java app I can choose a port and then the App sends and receives data on that port.

On windows I plug in a Bluetooth dongle which installs the necessary drivers and then I can launch my app.

How can I have this same set up on my raspberry pi?

I have the latest version of raspbian installed.

Comment: I found a similar request, you should achieve what you want by following this answer :
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/9127/26247

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to figure out the pairing and connecting process. I haven't looked if there's a handy ui available for rpi for this, but you can script it or do it by command line.

See https://wiki.debian.org/BluetoothUser for some instructions.